# creating table at runtime in vb.net, image control doesnt have imageurl proerty

Tags: vb.net, image, runtime

i am creating a table in vb.net code (htmltable) with htmltablerows and htmltablecell. I gave on image control but thatr control cant have the .imageurl property, which i need cause i have a handler image.ashx which brings image from the database.
heres' the code -

TD = New HtmlTableCell
Dim img As New HtmlImage()
img.ID = "image_" & rd("ID")
img.Style.Add("width", "100px")
img.Style.Add("height", "100px")
img.ImageUrl = "Image.ashx?id=" & rd("ID")

on the last line, "img.ImageUrl" i get this error -
'ImageUrl' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage'
how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`ImageUrl` is a member of the `System.UI.WebControls.Image` control.  By contrast, you are using the direct `HtmlImage` control which is rendered exactly as an *img* tag would be.  You should use the [Src property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlimage.src%28VS.71%29.aspx) of the HtmlImage control instead.